# javascript calling a function with params on window object

Tags: javascript, window

So I'm trying to call this method:

> refreshMoradaLabel = function(idPlaceHolder) {...};

With the window object:

> window [ refreshMoradaLabel('id') ] ();

But this doesn't seem to work. It's only when the method has no parameters.
Is there a way to work using the `window [ variable ] ()` syntax?

Edit;

ok here's the code:

moarada.jsp has the code with these methods:

```
<c:set var="methodOnClose" value="refreshDynamicValues" />
<c:if test="${empty fieldInstance || (not empty fieldInstance && isTramitacao)}">
  <c:set var="methodOnClose" value="refreshMoradaLabel(${dfieldId})" />
</c:if>
<a class="texto" href="#" onclick="editMoradaPopup('${dfieldId}','${methodOnClose}');" id="moradas_${dfieldId}"><img alt="${moradaDes}" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/icon/icon-pesquisa.png"></a>
```

> window.refreshMoradaLabel = function(idPlaceHolder) {

```
    alert("label:" +idPlaceHolder);
    if($F(idPlaceHolder) != '') {
        //Update label
        new Ajax.Updater(idPlaceHolder+'_label', 'moradaPopupLocaleAware.do2?method=getLabel', 
                {method: 'get', parameters: 'id='+$F(idPlaceHolder)});
    }

};
```

> window.editMoradaPopup= function(idPlaceHolder,method){
>       alert(idPlaceHolder);
>   Ext.onReady(function(){
>   action = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/moradaPopupLocaleAware.do2"; 
>   action += "?method=edit&id="+$(idPlaceHolder).value;

```
        action += "&idPlaceHolder="+idPlaceHolder;
        action += "&savemorada=true";
        action += "&window=winchoose";      
        return ExtWindowAll('${moradaDes}',action,'','html',true,true,true,650,400,true,true,'fit', method);
    });

};
```

The method ExtWindowAll eventually call code from another js file, that results calling a close window event, with the string of the method name(refreshMoaraLabel) including possible params:

> winchoose.on('close', function( p ) {
>           if(functionOnClose) {
>               alert("method: "+functionOnClose);
>               var substr=functionOnClose.match(/(([^)]*))/);
>               var param='';
>               if(substr!=null){
>                 param=substr[1];
>                 param="'"+param+"'";
>               }

```
        debugger;
        if(window[functionOnClose]) {
            window[functionOnClose](param);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:-

Window Context needs to take the function name as string.

```
 window ["refreshMoradaLabel"]();

  window ["refreshMoradaLabel"]('id');
```

Instead you are trying to invoke the method inside the window context.

window [ refreshMoradaLabel('id') ] (); when you do this you are trying to invoke the result of `refreshMoradaLabel('id')` which is undefined. since refreshMoradaLabel('id') gets executed first before even reaching the funciton call `()` of  window..

Comment: Please don't mind the space between `window ["refreshMoradaLabel"]();`

Comment: Ok guys thanks for the answers ill try tomorrow and return to approve.regards,

Comment: Havent been able to try this yet. Hope i can still choose an answer tomorrow.

Comment: ok no problem it will work check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J8t3D/ or rather http://jsfiddle.net/5ZG9B/

Comment: i think i'm having a problem getting the method. the window ['method']() call is on a different page then the one with the actual function.i've edited the answer to reflect a more detailed context.

Comment: @Maxrunner Put it in quotes window["functionOnClose"]

Comment: But by putting quotes in there wont it search for a variable called functionOnClose instead of the string i passed in the param of the method. funcitonOnClose can actually be something called "refreshSomething" or " refreshSomething(param);

Comment: See you need to put it in quotes if you are referring to a function using window since window[func] without quotes will search for a function with name function reference not name. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/X5cTe/

Comment: @Maxrunner were you able to refer to my Fiddle and check?

Comment: Never mind i was making a mistake by passing the full method with the brackets and params and not treating it in the on close event.

Answer (score 6):

The `window` object contains a property of name `refreshMoradaLabel`. To access the property, we can use either dot or square bracket notation:

`window.refreshMoradaLabel` or `window['refreshMoradaLabel']`

The value of that property is a function. To invoke it, we add parentheses: `window.refreshMoradaLabel('id')` or `window['refreshMoradaLabel']('id')`.