# How to use value of event page script in popup?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension which shows some values in popup. The values are fetched in event page script periodically.

```js
function load() {
  var value = fetch();
  // I would like to set this value to popup content.
}

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  if (alarm.name === "refresh") {
    load();
  }
});

chrome.alarms.create("refresh", {"periodInMinutes": 10});
```

I tried to get the popup window to change its content using `chrome.extension.getViews({ViewType: "popup"})` in event page script but it returned an empty array.

I know I can do it using storage but it seems to me overkill.

So how can I use the value in popup?

Comment: Popups simply don't exist when closed so use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or, depending on the actual goal, [chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) (in the popup, not in the event page).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Extension sendMessage to pageAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420528/chrome-extension-sendmessage-to-pageaction)

Comment: `value` is currently scoped to the `load()` function. If you want to access what `fetch()` returns from outside `load()` it needs to be assigned to a variable that has global scope.

Comment: Why do you feel that using `chrome.storage.local` is overkill?

Comment: Because I do not need the value is kept over sessions and I thought that adding permission `storage` introduces additional warning to user. But after trying to use `chrome.storage.local`, there were no such warning. I will use `chrome.storage.local`.