# Chrome Extension: Changing html of a chrome popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have made a Chrome extension to generate a summary of any document.I added the feature of opening the popup using the browser action icon, and now I want to add the same functionality using a context menu right-click action.

Now, when the popup2.html is opened using `windows.create()`, the window opens as it is and no message is sent to the popup.js script and in turn the `innerHtml` of the popup window which I opened in the *background.js* script is not modified.

I tried to use the [chrome.tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) method to send a message to the popup window but am not able to change its html there.

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  var context = "selection";
  var title = "See the Gist";
  var id = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts":[context],"id": "context_selection"});  
});

var open_window_ids=[]

function getSummary(selected) {

    var jsonData;

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/summarize',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(selected),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            jsonData = data;
        }
    });

    return jsonData;
}

console.log("Booting");

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {

    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "get_selected_text"}, function(response) {
        console.log('From button');
        if (response.selected_text == "") {
            document.body.innerHTML += "<h3 style='text-align: center'>No text selected! Select text and try again.</h3>";
        }
        else {
            var apiResponse = getSummary(response);
            console.log(apiResponse);
            if (!apiResponse)
            {
                document.getElementById("header").innerHTML += "<h3 class='heading'>API response unavailable.</h3>";
            }
            var summary_final = apiResponse.sentences;
            if (summary_final.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("header").innerHTML += "<h3 class='heading'>Not enough text selected to generate summary. Select larger block of text and try again.</h3>";
                document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML += "<div style='padding:15px;'>Powered by <a href='http://zippybots.com' target='_blank'><span id='link'>Zippybots</span></a></div>";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("header").innerHTML += "<h1 class='heading'>The Gist is.....</h1>";
                var para = "";
                for (var i = 0;i<summary_final.length;i++)
                {
                    para += summary_final[i]+" ";
                    if( i % 3 == 2) 
                    {
                        document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML += "<p class='point'>"+para+"</p>";    
                        para = "";
                    }
                }
                if (para) document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML += "<p class='point'>"+para+"</p>";
                document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML += "<div style='padding:15px;'>Powered by <a href='http://zippybots.com' target='_blank'><span id='link'>Zippybots</span></a></div>";
            }
        }
    });
});


chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab){
    if (info.menuItemId == "context_selection") {
        for (var i = open_window_ids.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            chrome.windows.remove(open_window_ids[i],function(){});
            open_window_ids.pop();
        }   
            // window.document.body.innerHTML += doc;
        var activeTab;
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            activeTab = tabs[0];
            chrome.windows.create({url: 'popup2.html',focused:true,type:'popup'},function(win){
                open_window_ids.push(win.id);
                displayCurrent(open_window_ids[0],activeTab.id,win);
            });
        });
    }
});

function displayCurrent(id,activeTabId,popupwindow){
    console.log("Got selection tab id :"+activeTabId);
    var popupTabId = popupwindow.tabs[0].id;
    console.log("Got popup tab id :"+popupTabId);

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTabId, {"message": "get_selected_text"}, function(response) {

        console.log("Resp:"+response.selected_text);
        if (response.selected_text == "") {
            console.log("Selected text is null");
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(popupTabId,{"message":"no_text_selected"},function (response){});
        }
        else {
            var apiResponse = getSummary(response);
            if (!apiResponse)
            {
                document.getElementById("header").innerHTML += "<h3 class='heading'>API response unavailable.</h3>";
            }
            var summary_final = apiResponse.sentences;
            if (summary_final.length == 0) {
                console.log("Summary length 0");
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(popupTabId,{"message":"not_enough_text"},function (response){});
            }
            else {
                console.log("Summary there");
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(popupTabId,{"message":"summary","data":summary_final},function (response){});   
            }
        }   
    });
}
```

**popup2.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="api-keys.js"/></script> -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                min-width: 750px;
                font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
                background: #f1f1f1;
                /*background: #2c001e;*/
            }
            #header{
                /*background: #dd4814;*/
                background: #2c001e;
                /*color: #dd4814;*/
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 1px;
            }
            #footer{
                /*background: #dd4814;*/
                background: #2c001e;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: right;
                min-height: 50px; 
            }
            #link{
                /*color: #fff;              */
                color: #dd4814;
            }
            .point{
                color: #333;                
                /*background: #2c001e;*/
                background: #f1f1f1;
                text-align: justify;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            #summary{
                background: #f1f1f1;
                /*background: #2c001e;*/
                max-width: 720px;
                font-weight: 300;   
                font-size:15px;
                font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, "libra sans", sans-serif;
                padding-left: 30px;
            }
            .heading{
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="header"></div>
            <!-- This will be populated when extension button is clicked -->
            <div id="summary"><br></div>
            <div id="footer">

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**content.js**

```
console.log("Content file loaded");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == "get_selected_text") {
        var selectedText = document.getSelection().toString();
        sendResponse({selected_text: selectedText});
        return true;
    }
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Selection Summarizer",
  "description": "A chrome extension that allows users to get a summary of a news article or large block of text.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],

      "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "content.js","popup.js"]

    }
  ],

  "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent" :false
    },


  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Summarize!"
  },

  "icons": { "16": "icons/icon16.png",
           "48": "icons/icon48.png",
          "128": "icons/icon128.png" },

  "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs","contextMenus",
    "http://127.0.0.1:5000/*","https://en.wikipedia.org/*"]
}
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == "no_text_selected") {
        console.log("no_text_selected");
        document.body.innerHTML += "<h3 style='text-align: center'>No text selected! Select text and try again.</h3>";
    }

    else if (request.message == "not_enough_text") {
        console.log("not enough text");
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML += "<h3 class='heading'>Not enough text selected to generate summary. Select larger block of text and try again.</h3>";
        document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML += "<div style='padding:15px;'>Powered by <a href='http://zippybots.com' target='_blank'><span id='link'>Zippybots</span></a></div>";
    }

    else if (request.message == "summary") {
        console.log("Summary printing");
        var summary_final = request.data;
        console.log(summary_final);
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML += "<h1 class='heading'>Summary</h1>";
        var para = "";
        for (var i = 0;i<summary_final.length;i++)
        {
            para += summary_final[i]+" ";
            if( i % 3 == 2) 
            {
                document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML += "<p class='point'>"+para+"</p>";    
                para = "";
            }
        }
        if (para) document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML += "<p class='point'>"+para+"</p>";
        document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML += "<div style='padding:15px;'>Powered by <a href='http://zippybots.com' target='_blank'><span id='link'>Zippybots</span></a></div>";
    }
    return true;
});
```

**content.js**

```
console.log("Content file loaded");
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == "get_selected_text") {
        var selectedText = document.getSelection().toString();
        sendResponse({selected_text: selectedText});
        return true;
    }
});
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="api-keys.js"/></script> -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="content.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
        <style>
            body{
                min-width: 550px;
                font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
                background: #f1f1f1;
                /*background: #2c001e;*/
            }
            #header{
                /*background: #dd4814;*/
                background: #2c001e;
                /*color: #dd4814;*/
                color: #fff;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 1px;
            }
            #footer{
                /*background: #dd4814;*/
                background: #2c001e;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: right;
                min-height: 50px; 
            }
            #link{
                /*color: #fff;              */
                color: #dd4814;
            }
            .point{
                color: #333;                
                /*background: #2c001e;*/
                background: #f1f1f1;
                text-align: justify;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            #summary{
                background: #f1f1f1;
                /*background: #2c001e;*/
                max-width: 720px;
                font-weight: 300;   
                font-size:15px;
                font-family: Ubuntu, Arial, "libra sans", sans-serif;
                padding-left: 30px;
            }
            .heading{
                margin-top: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div id="header"></div>
            <!-- This will be populated when extension button is clicked -->
            <div id="summary"><br></div>
            <div id="footer">

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. `Having problems` is too vague and doesn't tell us anything 2. Your contextMenus.onClicked callback invokes displayCurrent() which sends `{"message": "get_selected_text"}` but your popup.js doesn't check for that. 3. These types of problems are very hard to explain and diagnose but are easy to debug. Start using devtools properly. You can debug your background page script. You can also enable devtools `Auto-open devtools for popup`, you can use `debugger;` statement, `console.log` etc.

Comment: Is *popup2.html* actually *popup.html*? You appear to be loading your *popup.js* as both code for your popup and as a content script. Doing so is a Bad Idea™. Unless specifically designed to be included multiple places (e.g. libraries), your code should be in separate files which are only loaded into one context.

Comment: @wOxxOm: 1. Sorry about that. 2. That "get_selected_text" message calls a **content.js** file to select the text from the web page( I'm adding that to my question now).

Comment: @Makyen: No, the _popup.html_ is a different file with almost the same html code which is meant to open when the user clicks the browserAction button. On the other hand, _popup2.html_ is mean to open when the user clicks the contextMenu option. I am confused about which js scripts to link in these two files so any help there would be appreciated.

Comment: Related/partial duplicate: [Communicate between scripts in the background context (background script, browser action, page action, options page, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420772)

Answer (score 4):

You have two problems:

#### First problem

You are using [`tabs.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) when attempting to communicate with the script which is in the popup you have opened. As an HTML page contained within your extension, the scripts in that page run in the background context. Thus, `tabs.sendMessage()` will not work to communicate to that script. If you are wanting to send messages of that type, you need to use [`runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage). There are multiple ways you can communicate between scripts in the background context. For a more detailed discussion, please see [Communicate between scripts in the background context (background script, browser action, page action, options page, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420528/communicate-between-scripts-in-the-background-context-background-script-browse/41420772#41420772)

#### Second problem

You are trying to send a message to the *popup.js* script in the window you just opened immediately within the callback of `windows.create()`. At the time that callback is run, the window has begun to be created and a `windowId` has been assigned, but the content of the window does not yet exist (i.e. the DOM has not been built and the code in *popup.js* has not yet been run). Thus, there is no listener active, which results in the message not being received.

#### Solutions

The easy ways to solve these issues are:

1. Store the data in `storage.local` prior to the call to `windows.open()` and let the *popup.js* code get it from `storage.local` when it first runs, or
2. Initiate the transfer of the data from *popup.js* by sending a message from the *popup.js* code to your *background.js* (using [`runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)) requesting the data. Your *background.js* can then send the data back using the [`sendResponse`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-onMessage-sendResponse) function provided by [`runtime.onMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage).
3. Store the data in a variable in your *background.js* which is accessible from it's global scope. Your *popup.js* code can then directly access the variable in that scope after obtaining the background's `window` object with [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage).

It's also possible to wait to send the message from *background.js* until after *popup.js* has run, but that is any of: A) more complex, B) effectively the same as having the `runtime.sendMessage()` initiated from the popup, or C) not guranteed to actually be after the *popup.js* runs (e.g. just using a `setTimeout()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. I am actually trying to do what you mentioned because I was of the view that the callback(of `windows.create()`) would run after the window creation has finished(Isn't that what callbacks are meant to do?)

Comment: 1. What data are you talking about in (1)?  2. Would you rather have me use `windows.open()` instead of `chrome.windows.create()` ?

Comment: @UtkarshAgarwal, The data I'm talking about is the information you are trying to communicate to the popup. You can store in in a `storage.local` key like `messageToPopup2`, which the *popup2.js* code can read when it executes. Alternately, you can forgo the use of messages, or `storage.local` and just directly access the global scope variables in your *background.js* from *popup.js* using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`.

Comment: @UtkarshAgarwal, Please see updated answer, as I missed an issue in your code (first issue).